# Accuracy vs. Understanding In Science

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Suppose I have a theory **A** that **can** predict all experimental outcomes, **E**, in a particular domain of interest almost exactly.

Now suppose later a second theory is developed **B** that **cannot** predict experimental outcomes precisely, but instead can make a prediction within a certain range of **E**.

Now let us suppose that no one can understand how theory **A** produces the right answer.  Theory **A** just involves doing certain arithmetical sums and happens to work.

But let us suppose **B** is built up from more fundamental scientific ideas, and allows one to clearly conceptualise how the theory works (despite not being as accurate as **A**).

So my question is, does theory **B** have a place in science, given that **A** can already predict all experimental results in the domain of interest?

Put another way, is science done when it can predict the world, or is there still science in understanding it (even at the cost of accuracy)?

Comment: Well, newtonian physics is still a part of science, although it is weaker than relativity.

Comment: @rus9384, yes but suppose relativity was discovered first.  Would there be any need to discover Newtonian physics post relativity, and would this be in the realm of science?

Comment: After relativity newtonian model is an approximation. As approximation it'd be useful, but it does not reveal anything new from theoretical point.

Comment: @rus9384, that's right, so the newtonian/relativity example you gave initially doesn't quite match my scenario, where theory B comes second, and explains less.

Comment: The problem is that understanding better means greater accuracy. Or else I don't get what you mean by "understanding". Typically it is linked with predictions. There are many relativity simplifications, as well as quantum theories which were developed later. But they don't and can't give better understanding because they are weaker.

Comment: @rus9384, Feynman put it nicely in a video.  He describes the Mayans who could predict the movement of stars very well, but had no idea about gravity.  They crunched numbers and got the right answers.  But then maybe someone comes along with a hypothesis about a force called gravity, that at the time might not predict as well  as the Mayan's number crunching method. The Mayans may tell him to go away, as they can predict better.

Comment: For the ecologist Richard Levins, there was (or is? I'm not sure if he's still alive) an important tradeoff between predictive and explanatory power in building models.  Levins argued that you couldn't have a model that achieved both.  Take a look at this paper by philosopher of science Michael Weisberg:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6oYmzobonqoS2VtMzl4RXFpQk0

Comment: I personally believe the universe is running a complex mathematical equation, and the attempts to "understand" the equation are useless. To me, the job of science is to predict, not to make up explanations. **However**, if theory B allows better conceptualization, it seems that it would have to make better *intermediate* predictions that Theory A couldn't make. Analogy: a complicated mathematical proof may prove something, but a simpler proof (that proves less) may prove additional things on its way to the proof, and those additional proofs have value.

Comment: Yes, insight is often valued over accuracy, "*the purpose of computing is insight, not numbers*", as Hamming put it. The post describes almost exactly the relation between quantum chemistry (A) and the theory of chemical bonds (B), among many other exact/simplified model relations. Chemical bonds are strictly speaking fictions, but they allow one to do conceptualizing and ballpark estimates (sometimes quite accurate), whereas quantum chemistry is largely a black box with little insight, accessible only via computer simulations.

Comment: I think there's a valuable Kuhnian answer to be suggested here about scientific theory change being a gradual social process rather than something that needs to be absolutely captured as a snapshot in the moment, but I'm not really sufficiently well-read to give a good account.  Would anyone else be interested in picking this ball up and kicking it around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we've got a largely opaque computation (perhaps an artificial neural net) that can provide answers, we've got something of a dead end.  We can't extend it, and if it has slight inaccuracies we don't know how to adjust the model.

If we have a theory that the results come from these scientific principles, then we can probably extend it to other fields.  If there's discrepancies between the model and observations, we can investigate them, and see what other factors might be in play, or whether our original principles were slightly wrong.  (Example:  applying Newton's law of gravity to orbital mechanics resulted in the discoveries of Uranus and Neptune, but didn't handle Mercury.  It turned out that Newtonian mechanics are slightly wrong, and applying relativity makes Mercury's orbit work.)

One purpose of scientific theories is to summarize information, and an opaque calculation can't be summarized or simplified.  (For example, consider objects moving and colliding with each other.  In a frictionless vacuum, all we need to know to figure out how to calculate the results is a couple of conservation laws.)

Answer (score 1):

> does theory **B** have a place in science

As described, it's completely reasonable for theory **B** to have a place in science. It's even likely if it has properties such that it makes it easier to make useful predictions.

In fact, it's very common to make use of theories where we know that there are more accurate and more complete theories available. Newtonian mechanics, for example.

Now, you added two extra properties to your theories that deserve some discussion. You said

> Now suppose later a second theory is developed

The ordering of the discover of theories doesn't really matter in science. In practice, it may affect how prevalent the usage is and will likely affect the prestige of the theory (precedence is important to scientists if not to science) but utility usually trumps most other considerations.

> built up from more fundamental scientific ideas

This is probably the most philosophically interesting statement. It is often very useful to have a mental model of a theory that helps to intuit what is going on. Whether or not that mental model actually represents something fundamental is, however, often questionable.

This has shown to be particularly true for theories that probe beyond the limits of our senses. It does appear that we struggle to develop intuitive mental models at those extremes and scientists who probe those reaches tend to rely heavily on the mathematics as it's proven to be more reliable in practice.

Whether this is a inherent trait in humans or we just haven't developed the right mental models is, I believe, an open question.